# mongodb: only update document if is not updated

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have this function. Allow take a service only is not taken:
is taken only if the available param is true.

```
function takeService(req, res) {
  var serviceId = req.params.id;
  var driverId = req.body.driverId;

  Service.findById(serviceId, (err, service) =>{
    if (!err) {
      if (!service) {
        res.status(404).send({message: 'Not found'});
      } else {
        if (service.available === false ) {
          res.status(409).send({message: 'The service is taken'});
        } else {
          Service.findByIdAndUpdate(serviceId, {
            driverId, 
            status: 1, 
            available: false
          }, (err, serviceUpdated) =>{
            if (!err && serviceUpdated) {
              res.status(200).send({message: "tomado"});
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Schemas:

```
var ServiceSchema = Schema({
  clientId: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Client'
  },
  available: Boolean,
  routeId: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Route'
  },
  date: Date,
  radius: Number,
  driverId: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Driver'
  },
  status: Number,
  time: String,
  createdTime: Number,
  rateId: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Rate'
  }
});

var DriverSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  status: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  oneSignalId: String,
  plate: String,
  make: String,
  year: String,
  model: String,
  groupId: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'DriverGroup'
  }],
  unit: String,
  telephone: String
});
```

The problem is when two devices call to this function, in some cases both find the document and check if is available and then both update the same document. I am looking a some validation in the schema for autocheck this property.

Comment: You could change `findByIdAndUpdate`, or make a new `findAvailableByIdAndUpdate` that include `"available":true` in the mongo query.  If it doesn't update any documents, something else won the race.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the main issue is that two devices may think that a service is still available.

The ultimate cause of this is that there's a race condition between `findById` and `findByIdAndUpdate`: between those two calls, there's a window of time in which another request can change the document in the database.

To fix this, you can use the atomic [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command, which Mongoose exposes as (amongst others) `Model#findOneAndUpdate`.

Your code would become something like this:

```
function takeService(req, res) {
  var serviceId = req.params.id;
  var driverId  = req.body.driverId;

  Service.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id       : serviceId,
    available : true
  }, {
    driverId  : driverId,
    status    : 1,
    available : false,
  }, (err, service) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500);
    } else if (! service) {
      return res.status(409).send({message: 'The service is taken'});
    } else {
      return res.status(200).send({message: "tomado"});
    }
  });
}
```

There are a few differences with your original code that you should be aware of:

- you can't distinguish between a service not existing (invalid/unknown `serviceId`) and a service that is not available anymore; in both cases, the update will yield no result and a 409 response is sent back;
- `findOneAndUpdate` will return the *old* document, before it was updated. If you want to receive the updated document, pass the `new` option in the query:

  ```
  Service.findOneAndUpdate({ ... }, { ... }, { new : true }, (err, service) => { ... })
  ```
- I added an error handler in there, that sends back a 500 (*"Internal Server Error"*) response.